# Difference between address of variable in main and in function

Tags: c

Just a simple question, why the addresses  in function and in main aren't the same? I try to make printf implementation without `va_list` and this is necessary for me, or it's the better idea to implement it, but I want to know the answer earlier.

```
 void func (char *format, ...)
 { 

       char *p = (char *) &format + sizeof(format);

       char *s = format;
       for(;*s != '\0'; ++s) {
         if (*s == '%') { 
            switch (*(s+1))
            {

              case 'd':
                printf("%d - address\n", ((int *)p)); //This should point on second argument
                p += sizeof (int);
                ++s;
                break;
            }
         }
       }
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a=2123213;
    printf("%d - address\n",&a);
    func("text%d",a);
}
```

Comment: Just for my understanding: what's wrong with `va_list`?

Comment: a is passed by _value_, i.e. pushed on the stack as actual parameter to `func` (essentially it is a _copy_ on another position on the stack). (Yes. I know, c doesn't neccessarily have a stack, but you get the idea, right?)

Comment: You should print pointer values (that is, addresses) using `%p`, not `%d`.

Comment: So how the value can be taken, when I can't get the "parent" address? @StephanLechner I'm studying, I have an assignment to do this in this way

Comment: Your assumption that the second parameter can be found by adding the size of the first parameter is original.

Comment: You can't get, and don't need, the "parent" address.  When you call `func()`, it gets a new copy of `a`'s value.  If your handrolled argument-accessing code works, you may succeed in plucking the passed value off of the stack, but yes, the address will be different.  It will be the address of the passed copy in the stack frame, not the address of `a` in the parent.

Comment: When you call `printf()` and pass the address of `a` you use `&a`, if you just use `a` you will get its value.  Same with `func()`.  If you need the address then you have to pass it as `&a`.

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", *((int *)p)); ` (note the extra `*`), and see if you get `2123213`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I tried, but this doesn't work, it shows `1`..

Comment: @jakub1998 In that case, you've shown that your homegrown arg-popping code is not working.  (This is not too surprising, since this is hard to get right, and not guaranteed to work at all.)  I suggest fishing around, like this:  `int i; for i = -4; i <= 4; i++) printf("%d: %d\n", i, *(int *)((char *)&format + i * sizeof(int)));`

Comment: Thanks, I found it, the value is 12 , but this is another suprising fact for me, why it's 12, when `sizeof(format)` is 8?

Comment: @jakub1998 Probably no one here can answer that.  The people who wrote your compiler might be able to.  They might have done all sorts of crazy things in setting up the call stack, *but* they also gave you a `va_arg` mechanism that knows how to undo it.  But since you've decided not to use that, you get to try to reverse-engineer all the crazy things they did.  This won't be easy, and it'll be an ongoing maintenance nightmare, but... you'll learn a lot!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are on the right way; The way how a C compiler passes parameters to functions is mostly unspecified; it may decide to use registers, the stack, or both; and it also may vary the offsets between register arguments and stacked arguments; So all your assumptions may hold, but they may not hold any more for different compilers or different platforms.
Maybe your compiler lets you somehow control argument passing, but there is no standard way of doing this.

C standard introduces `va_list` structure and associated macros in order to get independent from these implementation details. Use this; other ways are very likely undefined behaviour (e.g. adding an integral value to a pointer such that it points beyond the last element of an "array" or accessing the element one past the last element through such a pointer is UB; your code actually does this).

Comment: The C standard uses the phrase "implementation defined" in a way that goes beyond just saying that it's defined by the implementation. Anything that's implementation-defined must be documented. Parameter passing conventions are *unspecified*. The implementation must make parameter passing work correctly, but it needn't document how it does so.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: thanks for clarification. Adapted the answer accordingly.